# Why “que”, not “qui”, in “pays que sont …”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

I can't understand why the correct relative pronoun is not 'qui' in the sentence below.

- La Slovénie a beau se trouver au cœur de l'Europe, à deux pas de pays touristiques incontournables **que** sont l'Autriche et l'Italie, elle reste un grand mystère pour de nombreuses personnes.

Comment: *Au cœur de l'Europe, la Slovénie, qui reste un grand mystère pour de nombreuses personnes, se trouve à deux pas de pays touristiques incontournables qui sont l'Autriche et l'Italie.*

Answer (score 5):

> La Slovénie a beau se trouver au cœur de l'Europe, à deux pas de pays touristiques incontournables que sont l'Autriche et l'Italie, elle reste un grand mystère pour de nombreuses personnes.

Le pronom relatif "qui" représente le nom qui fait l'action (sujet):  *La pomme qui tombe*. Qu'est-ce qui tombe ? *La pomme*.

Ici il s'agit d'une tournure typiquement française, "ce sont", et dans la phrase on emploie *que* qui sert d'attribut à *sont* dont le sujet est *l'Autriche et l'Italie*. Quels sont les pays touristiques incontournables ? L'Autriche et l'Italie. Que sont l'Autriche et l'Italie ? Ce sont des pays touristiques incontournables.

Comme dans :

> Les dangers que représentent les tuyaux en plomb.

ou bien

> Je compte bien saisir l'opportunité qu'offre la plateforme pour proposer une configuration d'étude en collaboration avec un expérimentateur.

Comment: On comprend l'explication, mais il faut faire attention au fait qu'on ne peut normalement employer « Qui sont … ? » que pour des personnes (*qui* est un pronom interrogatif en début de question).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Merci. Est-ce mieux d'utilise Qu'est-ce qui sont ?

Comment: Pour *la pomme* (ou *les pommes* si c'était au pluriel), « Qu'est-ce qui tombe ? » serait une question bien formée qui porte sur le sujet du verbe. Pour la copule *être*, une question sur le sujet grammatical paraitrait artificielle. On formule en général la question de façon à ce qu'elle porte sur l'objet : « Qu'est-ce **que** c'est ? », « Qu'est-ce qu'une pomme ? », « Que sont les pommes ? », etc. Et lorsqu'on cherche à identifier on utilise « Qui est le / Qui sont les … » pour des personnes ou « Quel est le / Quels sont les … » pour des inanimés.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je viens de modifier la question avec la pomme. Qu'est-ce qui tombe ? La  pomme. Alors comment reformuler ces deux questions ?   **Qui sont des pays touristiques incontournables ?** L'Autriche et l'Italie. **Que sont l'Autriche et l'Italie ?** Ce sont des pays touristiques incontournables. E.g. Quels pays sont des pays touristiques incontournables ?  Mais à quelle question répondre " Ce sont des pays touristiques incontournables" ?

Comment: J'étais encore en train de modifier mon commentaire :) Oui « Quels sont les » fonctionne dans le premier cas, mais ça devient compliqué de comprendre l'explication puisqu'on perd la ressemblance avec l'exemple de la pomme. Pour le deuxième cas, il fonctionne très bien tel qu'il est actuellement rédigé.

Answer (score 3):

There is   essential information about this pronoun on this [site](https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/cours/le-pronom-relatif-que-francais-facile.html).

In this context "que" has the function of "attribut du sujet"; "que" stands for "pays touristiques incontournables"; in a clause where no replacement by a pronoun is used this is the function of  "pays touristiques incontournable";

- L'Autriche et l'Italie sont des pays touristiques incontournables.

So, when "que" is put in the place of that (pays touristiques incontournables) it's got the same function.

Why has been "que" designated for this function seems to be that if "qui" had been chosen, this pronoun having also the function of a subject there wouldn't have been a way to tell sometimes whether who or what represented "qui" was attributed something or doing the action. As "que" can only be COD and that "être" has no COD, there is no risk of confusion.

It might be useful to consider that in English there is no difference;

- The opposite, what these assertions are, he refutes.

(However, the best translations into English do not necessarily have to be by means of "what"; this pronoun can sometimes be done away with for the better of the translation.)

Answer (score 1):

Austria and Italy are not subjects in that sentence, so 'qui' does not apply

Comment: I thought they are subjects: doesn't it mean "l'Autriche et l'Italie sont des pays touristiques incontournables"?

Comment: No it means 'very close to the two unavoidable tourist destinations that are Austria and Italy'.  No 'sont' anywhere :-)

Comment: This seems to contradict the answer by LPH. My understanding was that "des pays touristiques incontournables que sont l'Autriche et l'Italie" means, in English, "the unavoidable tourist destinations that Austria and Italy are": "Austra and Italy" is the subject of the relative clause, but there is inversion so the word "sont" comes before rather than after. "que **sont** l'Autriche et l'Italie" certainly contains the word "sont".

Comment: (In English, I think "the two unavoidable tourist destinations that are Austria and Italy" might also conceivably involve inversion, but since "that" doesn't inflect for case, there isn't any obvious way to tell)

Answer (score 1):

Something doesn't work in the sentence the OP posted, I think it should read :

- La Slovénie a beau se trouver au cœur de l'Europe, à deux pas **des** pays touristiques incontournables que sont l'Autriche et l'Italie, elle reste un grand mystère pour de nombreuses personnes.

If you you  want to keep *à deux pas de* instead of *à deux pas des*, you'd have to say :

- La Slovénie a beau se trouver au cœur de l'Europe, à deux pas de pays touristiques incontournables **comme/comme le sont** l'Autriche et l'Italie, elle reste un grand mystère pour de nombreuses personnes.

For *que sont l'Autriche et l'Italie* to be used with *pays*, *pays* has to be definite.  In other words

- *les pays touristiques incontournables que sont l'Autriche et l'Italie*

is ok, whereas

- *des pays touristiques incontournables que sont l'Autriche et l'Italie*

is not acceptable because *pays* is indefinite or indeterminate.

In *à deux pas de pays…*, *pays* is indefinite, no article is used, whereas in *à deux pas des pays*, *pays* is definite, *des* here is the contraction of *de les*.