# Une phrase problématique (?)

Tags: syntaxe, phrase

Sur une affiche, j'ai lu :
[image]

Selon moi, la phrase est problématique. Je connais la tournure standard '[que sont](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34659/why-que-not-qui-in-pays-que-sont)' au lieu de 'qui sont'. Je crois quand même que 'qui sont' va mieux ici.

De plus, la répétition du verbe 'sont' me parait un peu gauche.
Après le deuxième 'sont', je pense qu'il manque l'accord (acteurs).

Je ne comprends pas non plus à quoi sert 'le' dans 'de le réussir'.

Je trouve que la phrase a besoin de virgules, voire d'être réécrite.

L'auteur de la phrase est un locuteur natif du français ayant fait des études d'ingénieur.

Comment: J'aurais mis une virgule avant "*sont acteurs*" pour la lisibilité et probablement un *s* à *acteurs*, mais à part ça la phrase ne me choque pas plus que ça. Elle aurait pu être mieux tournée mais elle reste lisible et compréhensible selon moi.

Comment: Il y aussi une imprécision : les acteur[s] en question sont-ils les étudiants seuls ou bien les étudiants plus les enseignants et enseignants chercheurs...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. *qui sont* et *que sont* ne sont pas interchangeables. L'un introduit le prédicat, l'autre le sujet, l'ordre étant inversé. Si on reconstruit cette phrase en mettant les enseignants en premier on aurait :

> nos enseignants et enseignants-chercheurs **sont** des chefs de projets et des référents techniques qui accompagnent les étudiants ingénieurs ...

2. Il est vrai que la répétition de *sont* n'est pas très euphonique, mais ce n'est ni inattendu, ni erroné. On pourrait dire *ont le rôle de* ou *servir*, etc., si on voulait l'éviter.
3. Après cette phrase relative on revient à la proposition principale :

> Les étudiants ingénieurs de dernière année sont acteur de ce projet ...

À première vue on dirait bien qu'*acteur* devrait être *acteurs*, mais en français, [si chaque projet n'a qu'un acteur, on utilise le singulier](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49126/12688). Je crois que c'est ce qui passe ici, mais je suis un peu incertain, vu que cet extrait ne décrit pas le projet pour qu'on puisse en vérifier la nature, et qu'il serait très facile d'omettre cet *s* par accident sans le remarquer.

4. *le* fait référence à *ce projet* : *réussir* peut être un verbe transitif, alors on peut *réussir un projet*. C'est le cas ici.
5. Oui, on doit ajouter une virgule après « enseignants-chercheurs » qui correspondrait à celle qui suit *année*. Je suggérerait à l'auteur de mettre une pause après *ce projet* aussi, soit une virgule, soit un point pour commencer une nouvelle phrase.

Comment: On peut dire "inversé" ou "interverti". Attention inverti est du vocabulaire chimique ou bien assez connoté (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inverti).

Comment: @XouDo Merci, c'est noté !

Answer (score 1):

On utilise le pronom relatif « que » car il a la fonction d’attribut du sujet et non de sujet dans cette proposition subordonnée relative. Le sujet de la proposition est nos enseignants. Qui est réservé à la fonction de sujet dans ce genre de proposition.

Personnellement, j’aurais mis un -s à acteurs.